# Text Editing Newbie Question

Tags: text-editor

I have just started playing around with text editing using Text Wrangler. I have real estate sales data cut and pasted from a web site on which I have searched and deleted unwanted data and cleaned up the tabs and spaces nicely. However each data record is still split over 2 lines. One line starts with a letter (persons name) and the next starts with an address (a digit). This pattern repeats all the way down the document. How do I say "if line break is followed on next line with a starting digit, replace line break with a tab"

I assume that would put each record on one line ?

Comment: Have you tried regular expression matching, combined with the `\n` line break character?

Comment: I guess thats what I'm asking, what is the correct grep pattern. I was using \r (mac) as opposed \n (unix) but neither work. What I think should work is find: \r +[D] replace:\t note i got the example back to front above the first line starts with a digit the 2nd with a letter.

Comment: I'm out of my depth with regex, sorry. That's why I didn't post a proper answer! Retag your question with regex and maybe you'll get more love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want it like:

```
Visitor82   123 E. Text Street ...
```

To do this in Text Wrangler:

1. Search > Find
2. Tick the 'Grep' option
3. In the Find Box type:

   <kbd>(?(?!\r\d)then)\r</kbd>
4. In the Replace Box type (or whatever delimiter you would like):

   <kbd>\x20</kbd>

~ Enjoy!

[image: Text Grepping!]

Comment: Brilliant ! I had to use D rather than d to represent any non digit character but that worked. Now I will try and work out why ;-) Thanks @ioi

Comment: Interesting, \d denotes [digit] and \D [not a digit], so that's got me scratching my head! I'm glad it worked for you; I love Regex, it's language theory and mathematics all rolled into one. ;-)